# how to make default text column where comparision binary (case sensitive and trim)

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if this is duplicated, but I don't know how to find about the question.

Hi, this my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_Valor` (
    `idLog_Valor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    `Valor` text binary  NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`idLog_Valor`) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `log_Valor` (Valor) VALUES ('teste');
INSERT INTO `log_Valor` (Valor) VALUES ('teste ');
```

I have 2 rows:

```
1  | 'teste'
2  | 'teste '
```

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM log_Valor where valor = 'teste'
```

It returns the two rows.

How do I make default comparison case sensitive and to not trim without having to specify in the query BINARY?

Comment: What does this have to do with case sensitivity? Your question is about trailing spaces, not case.

Comment: sorry i will edit , but i need both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE` instead of `=`.

```
SELECT * FROM log_Valor WHERE valor LIKE 'teste';
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/195f4/1)

Comment: I know i can use Like, but can this be default in this table? i mean, when user runs SELECT * FROM log_Valor where valor = 'teste', it return only the single row, whitout specify anything in query?

Comment: ahh, you mean i need to user varchar?

Comment: No, `VARCHAR` discards the trailing spaces when you insert, so it won't work. `CHAR` stores the trailing spaces, but `=` ignores them.

Comment: For case sensitivity you can use a case-sensitive collation on the column. But I don't think there's any way to make `=` check trailing spaces.

Comment: Ok, i search and it seems to be expected as sql standards :( i was trying to create a LogValueDictionary to store values of fields for audit logs to avoid duplicate text, but ok....some logs will not register rtrim changes :P... i will mark your help as anwser to show my gratitude for your efforts in help me